# Изменения изображений при скролле, что бы получился эффект видео. js

Tags: javascript, html, css, изображения, прокрутка

Есть блок на странице который находится в определенном месте. Нужно сделать так, что бы когда пользователь доскролил до него, в блоке началась смена изображений и так же в обратную сторону. Я нашел один код – он работает идеально но на весь body. T.е. изображения начинают меняться не доходя до блока. Мой первый вопрос на стаковерфлоу. Сори если что то не так и спасибо!
тут пример:

https://jsfiddle.net/DenisKhirug/jmkec3tf/

```js
 var images = ["https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg"],
   len = images.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = images[i]
 };
 
 
 
 window.onload = function()   {
   var videoElem = document.querySelector('.video'),
     scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
     clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
     maxScroll = Math.max(scrollHeight, clientHeight) - clientHeight,
     step = maxScroll / len;


   window.onscroll = function()  {
     var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
     for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       if (i * step + step >= scrolled) break
     }
     videoElem.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
   }
 }
```

```css
body{
    height: 1500px;
}
.container{
  max-width:600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  color:#fff;
  display: flex;
  
}

.text {
  display: flex
  flex: 0 50%;
  width: 300px;
}
.text h1{
  padding: 20px;
}

.video {
    display:flex;
    flex: 0 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background-image: url("https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>video</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="text">
  <h1>эти изображения должны меняться только когда экран на этом блоке</h1>
</div>
<div class="video"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужна дополнительная проверка на то, что Ваш блок находится в текущий момент в viewport экрана

```
 var images = ["https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg", "https://scandinews.fi/assets/image-cache/images/2015/4/0/1-0.246.2ee62299.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/181/86/29/bely_d_850.jpg", "https://kubnews.ru/upload/iblock/867/86789464c61c450aeddf67ca965dc093.jpg", "https://cdnimg.rg.ru/img/content/168/10/26/kotik_d_850_d_850.jpg"],
   len = images.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = images[i]
 };
 
 
 
 window.onload = function()   {
   var videoElem = document.querySelector('.video'),
     scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
     clientHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
     maxScroll = Math.max(scrollHeight, clientHeight) - clientHeight,
     step = maxScroll / len;


    var isInViewport = function (elem) {
      var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
      return (
          bounding.top >= 0 &&
          bounding.left >= 0 &&
          bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
          bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
      );
  };


   window.onscroll = function()  {
    if (isInViewport(videoElem)) {
       var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
       for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         if (i * step + step >= scrolled) break
       }
       videoElem.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Проверка проходит. но работает не так. В оригинале это работает хорошо, т.к. первая картинка выводится в начале и последняя в конце. после подключения проверки такое ощущение что первая картинка эта та, которая должна была быть где то в середине. и выводиться всего пару картинок вместо всех.  Пример: Без проверки выводятся все 30 картинок, а с вашей проверкой только две. Надеюсь понятно. Буду благодарен если поможете дорешать этот вопрос)